# Do "time points" and "durations" have an algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, type-theory

The C++ programming language has two types that are used to represent time: `time_point` and `duration`. As the name suggests:

- `time_point` represents a specific point in time
- `duration` is, well, a duration

Mathematical operations can be made mixing these two types, namely:

- `duration` + `duration` -> `duration`
- `time_point` - `time_point` -> `duration`
- `time_point` + `duration` -> `time_point`
- `time_point` + `time_point` is not defined

I noticed that $(\{\texttt{duration},\texttt{time_point}\},+)$ looks like it is *almost* isomorphic to the group $({0,1},+)$. If we replace `duration` with 0 and `time_point` with 1 in the above equations we get:

- $0 + 0 = 0$
- $1 - 1 = 0$
- $1 + 0 = 1$

The isomorphism is not perfect, in that $1+1$ is well defined in $(\{0,1\},+)$, but `time_point` + `time_point` is not.

My question is: can it be shown, perhaps using category theory, that the types `duration` and `time_point` form some kind of known algebraic structure?

Comment: Looks like an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) where durations are translations.

Comment: @lhf ... and an 1-dimensional real one! (+1)

Answer (score 6):

As already been said in the comments, the relevant algebraic structure is a one-dimensional affine space. This concept originates in geometry, where it is sometimes convenient to distinguish points from vectors. You can add/subtract vectors, you can add a vector to a point, you can subtract points to get a vector, but you cannot add points meaningfully. With this correspondence, durations are vectors and time points are points. Note that these are still two separate sets, connected via common operations.

The analogy with $(0,1)$ that you've discovered is commonly used to put an affine space $A$ and the associated vector space $V$ to a common ground. Take the vector space $V \oplus \mathbb R$. The vectors from $V$ form a subspace of $V \oplus \mathbb R$ of the form $\{(v,0) | v \in V\}$. Now, pick any point $p_0 \in A$ and define an embedding of $A$ into $V \oplus \mathbb R$ by mapping $p \in A$ to $(p - p_0, 1)$ (note that $p-p_0 \in V$). This embedding has several useful features:

- Vectors behave exactly as they did in $V$, just with a zero attached as an extra coordinate
- Adding a vector to a point gives an element of $V \oplus \mathbb R$ with the last coordinate equal to $1$, i.e. a point
- Subtracting two points gives an element of $V \oplus \mathbb R$ with the last coordinate equal to $0$, i.e. a vector
- Adding two points gives an element of $V \oplus \mathbb R$ with the last coordinate equal to $2$, which is neither a point nor a vector (although one can speculate on the meaning of such elements)
- In an affine space, any linear combination of points with the sum of coeffieients equal to $1$ is meaningful and produces a point, while a combination with the sum of coeffieients equal to $0$ is meaningful as well and produces a vector. Likewise, if one takes a linear combination of points embedded in $V \oplus \mathbb R$, the last coordinate will be just the sum of coefficients of the combination, giving $1$ (a point) or $0$ (a vector) for the aforementioned cases.
- This embedding allows affine transformations to be represented as linear operators and thus as matrices, which is extensively used in 3D graphics.

However, note that none of the standard data types of C++ actually form a field (and only a few of them form a ring), due to various reasons (signed integer overflow is UB, floating-points are not even associative, etc), and durations & time points are subject to all those problems as well. What it means is that while this correspondence between durations & time points and affine spaces is a mentally fruitful one, care must be taken since one cannot in general use this as a strict mathematical model and/or prove anything about these C++ types.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Very interesting!